# How I can control the environment when building gcc or clang?

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, clang, configure

Tipically you use `CC` or `CXX` or similar variables to control and configure your build when using a `configure` script.

Assuming that I need a much more reliable configuration, I would like to use something with a "chroot-philosophy", meaning that I would like to configure and build my compiler in an environment that has no executables in the `PATH` and no other environment variables other then the ones that I'm explicitly passing.

There is a solution to sandbox this kind of builds ?

I would like to get an error from my build instead of default actions or having `configure` scripts picking executables from the system folders .

Comment: `/bin/env -i /bin/sh -c "PATH= ./configure blah blah"`.